# Height of a bottle, given internal water levels in two orientations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, volume

[image]

$\pi h$ and $ 3^2\pi h$

Am I supposed to insert 20 cm and 28 cm somewhere in the expression?

I have no idea how to start off this question.

Comment: Hint: the volume of the air bubble is the same in the two cases.

Comment: Could you please help me to find solution for this? @Arthur

Comment: Why did you write the formula $3\pi r^2h$? Try to identify meaningful parts of the figure, then describe their dimensions with numbers or symbols and write formulas for their volumes. There are clever ways to solve this problem and not-so-clever-but-get-the-job-done ways, but I don't know any that don't involve (some way or other) the steps I just recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be the height of the column of air when the bottle is right-side-up. Since the *volume* of this empty space remains unchanged when the bottle is turned over, we have
$$\pi\cdot1^2\cdot x=\pi\cdot3^2\cdot(x-8)$$
where the 8 comes from the given difference in water level between the two orientations. Solving for $x$:
$$x=9(x-8)=9x-72$$
$$8x=72$$
$$x=9$$
The height of the bottle is therefore $20+x=20+9=29$ centimetres.